# I am trying to make a page shrink to fit a mobile screen

Tags: html, css, mobile

I am attempting to make a page shrink to fully fit a mobile screen but with an image on one side, and an iframe form on the other, it is being pushed to the right on a phone, also does the same with a long header. I have tried every "meta viewport" combination I have seen on here and nothing is working. Is this possible or am I missing something? Thanks! There's a lot of code so not sure what should be posted here.

Link to the page: http://marketing.bigkiteconsulting.com/acton/fs/blocks/showLandingPage/a/9748/p/p-0028/t/page/fm/0

Comment: Google 'responsive grid system', start from scratch using that as a guide. It will be far far easier in the long run.

Comment: Have you tried anything else besides adding meta viewport tags to your page. Any responsive css techniques? Media Queries, other methods? Are you allowed to use a framework such as Bootstrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so i gather your not wanting the form to be above the div with the image and paragraph?  that might give you the best look.

The main problem is the image, you need to remove the width and height from the image, and set the width to a percentage using css

```
<img src="http://marketing.bigkiteconsulting.com/cdnr/57/acton/attachment/9748/f-0037/1/-/-/-/-/image.jpg" border="0" style="width:100%;">
```

As far as the form, its too wide itself.  I would suggest  wrapping the last name underneath the first name, and make the email input box smaller, however if that iframe is coming form a third party there's not much you can do to it unless CORS is enabled. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing